# How to create a Guid with all zero elements?

Tags: c#, guid, zero

How to create a `Guid` that all of its elements are zero. i.e. `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`. I could use:

`Guid.Parse("{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}")`

But is there any easier method for that ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
var guid = Guid.Empty;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new Guid

```
var guid = new Guid();
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but this also works:

```
Guid guid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure PowerShell is here:

```
> [Guid]::Empty

Guid
----
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```